# Oracle sql join against extracted values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to reconcile data from 2 different tables where I need to carry out a concatenation and substr to create columns that I can use to carry out a match against.The following separate queries reflect the select statements from each table that produces the matching values that reflect `sitenn.zonenn` (e.g. `site12.zone20`) as nodename.

```
SELECT distinct(REGEXP_SUBSTR(B.NODE_NAME,'*site*.*')) as nodename
FROM OPC_ACT_MESSAGES A,OPC_NODE_NAMES B 
WHERE A.MESSAGE_GROUP = 'Ebts_Status_Alarms' 
AND A.SEVERITY <> 2 
AND A.NODE_ID = B.NODE_ID;

SELECT 'site'||site_id||'.zone'||zone_id as nodename
FROM aw_active_alarms 
GROUP BY site_id,zone_id;
```

I need to write a query that select all nodenames from one table that do not exist in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left join` to find it. It is faster than `minus`,`not in`,`not exists` etc.

```
SELECT a.nodename 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT( regexp_substr(B.node_name, '*site*.*') ) AS nodename 
        FROM   opc_act_messages A, 
               opc_node_names B 
        WHERE  A.message_group = 'Ebts_Status_Alarms' 
               AND A.severity <> 2 
               AND A.node_id = B.node_id
        ) a 
LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 'site' 
                         || site_id 
                         || '.zone' 
                         || zone_id AS nodename 
                  FROM   aw_active_alarms 
                  GROUP  BY site_id, 
                            zone_id
        ) b 
ON a.nodename = b.nodename 
WHERE  b.nodename IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks this does exactly what I'm looking for (as do other suggestions) and adopts the best practice.  Just one question I'm not clear as to the purpose of the last line -- where b.nodename is null

Comment: if you don't give `WHERE  b.nodename IS NULL` then you will get all the `a.nodename`. For the records which are there in `a` and not in `b`,  `left join` from `a` to `b` will give `b.nodename` as `null`. You can get only these records to get your output, hence the `where` condition.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way: use `MINUS`

```
SELECT distinct(REGEXP_SUBSTR(B.NODE_NAME,'*site*.*')) as nodename
FROM OPC_ACT_MESSAGES A,OPC_NODE_NAMES B 
WHERE A.MESSAGE_GROUP = 'Ebts_Status_Alarms' 
AND A.SEVERITY <> 2 
AND A.NODE_ID = B.NODE_ID 
MINUS
SELECT 'site'||site_id||'.zone'||zone_id as nodename
FROM aw_active_alarms 
GROUP BY site_id,zone_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

would this work?

```
WITH t1
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT
                (REGEXP_SUBSTR (B.NODE_NAME, '*site*.*')) AS nodename
           FROM OPC_ACT_MESSAGES A, OPC_NODE_NAMES B
          WHERE     A.MESSAGE_GROUP = 'Ebts_Status_Alarms'
                AND A.SEVERITY <> 2
                AND A.NODE_ID = B.NODE_ID),
     t2
     AS (  SELECT 'site' || site_id || '.zone' || zone_id AS nodename
             FROM aw_active_alarms
         GROUP BY site_id, zone_id)
SELECT *
  FROM t1
 WHERE t1.nodename NOT IN (SELECT nodename FROM t2)
```